# client program crashes when connect to server after disconnect Qt

Tags: c++, qt, tcp, qtcpsocket

I am implementing client side of TCP-Ip server based on Qt but the program crashes when I closed connection and start again by hitting connect button.

*Overview of project*. I have Qwidget ( main application) with 2 lineEdit for user to input port number  and server Ip address.
It also has 2 button that connect to server and disconnect. On hitting connect button , it will call constructor of client socket and call connectToHost.

*Testing*: Tried testing on same computer  with server running on port 6000 and ip address 127.0.0.1.

*Problem*: When I launch Client application.And input port number and address and hit connect button it connects successfully. And I can write to server successfully. then I click disconnect button and it disconnects successfully but after that if I connect again by clicking connect button it crashes. I know problem is with tcpSocket but have no idea how to fix it.

clientAgent( QWidget appilciation ).h

```
namespace Ui {
class ClientAgent;
}

class ClientAgent : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit ClientAgent(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~ClientAgent();

private:
    Ui::ClientAgent  *ui;
    ClientForTest    *tcpSockForTest;

// Qwidget declartion
below
....

private slots:
    void startClient();
    void stopClient();

public slots:
    void getCliReqTextChanged();

};
```

ClientAgent.cpp

```
ClientAgent::ClientAgent( QWidget *parent ) :
          QWidget(parent),
          ui( new Ui::ClientAgent )
{

// Widget declartion and initilisation
// Layout design etc

   //define signals and slots for Client
  // signals and slots

  connect( btnStartClient,  SIGNAL( clicked() ), this, SLOT( startClient() ) );
  connect( btnStopClient,   SIGNAL( clicked() ), this, SLOT( stopClient() ) );

// for write
connect( lEditCliReq,  SIGNAL( textChanged(const QString& ) ), this, SLOT( getCliReqTextChanged() ) );

  ui->setupUi( this );

}

ClientAgent::~ClientAgent()
{
    delete ui;
}


void ClientAgent::startClient()
{
  qDebug() << " we are in strt Clinet";
  qDebug() << " connecting ";

  // get server address and port number from GUI

  QString testAddr = lEditAddr->text();
  QString testPort = lEditPrt->text();

  tcpSockForTest = new ClientForTest( testAddr, testPort.toInt(), this );

  if( tcpSockForTest->connectToServer() == true )
   {
      lblCliStatus->setText(" connected ....");
   }
  else
   {
      lblCliStatus->setText(" failed to connect....");
   }

}

void ClientAgent::stopClient()
{
  qDebug() << " disconnecting ";
  tcpSockForTest->disconnectToServer();
  delete tcpSockForTest;
}
```

ClientForTest.h

```
class ClientForTest : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  ClientForTest( QString hostAddr, quint16 portNum, QObject *parent );

  bool connectToServer();
  void disconnectToServer();
  QString getStoreMsgFrmCliReq( ) const;

  void writeToTest(const QString& stripCmd );
  void executeSignals();

    ~ClientForTest();

signals:
  void sigSendData();

public slots:
  void connectedToTest();
  void connectionClosedByServer();
  void error();

private:
   QTcpSocket   *sockFortest;
   QString       hostName;
   quint16       portNumber;
   quint16       nextBlockSize;
   QString       storeLineEditMsg;// store message from lineEditCliReq;

  };
```

ClientForTest.cpp

```
ClientForTest::ClientForTest( QString hostAddr, quint16 portNum, QObject *parent ) :
                            hostName( hostAddr ),
                            portNumber( portNum ),
                            QObject( parent )
{
  connect( sockFortest, SIGNAL( connected() ), this, SLOT( connectedToTest() ) );
  connect( sockFortest, SIGNAL( disconnected() ), this, SLOT( connectionClosedByServer() ) );
  connect( sockFortest, SIGNAL( error( QAbstractSocket::SocketError ) ), this, SLOT( error() ) );

  storeLineEditMsg = "";
}
void ClientForTest::executeSignals()
{
// actually I need toplace itin constructor will do later on
 connect( this,  SIGNAL( sigSendData() ), this, SLOT( connectedToTest() ) );
}

ClientForTest::~ClientForTest()
{

  sockFortest->close();
  delete sockFortest;
}

bool ClientForTest::connectToServer()
{
  sockFortest = new QTcpSocket( this->parent() ); // COULD be Probelm here but how to fix it?
  sockFortest->connectToHost( hostName, portNumber );
  nextBlockSize = 0;
  executeSignals();
  return sockFortest->waitForConnected(1000);
}

void ClientForTest::disconnectToServer()
{
  sockFortest->close();
  //sockFortest.close();
  qDebug() << "in disconnect for Test ";
  emit updateLabelinParent( updateStatusDis );
}


void ClientForTest::connectionClosedByServer()
{

  qDebug() << "connection closed by server ";
  if( nextBlockSize != 0xFFFF )
  {
    disconnectToServer();
  }
}

void ClientForTest::error()
{
  qDebug() << "in error ";
  disconnectToServer();
}

void ClientForTest::writeToTest( const QString& stripCmd )
{
  storeLineEditMsg = stripCmd;
  if( sockFortest->state() == QTcpSocket::UnconnectedState )
  {
      sockFortest->close();
      delete sockFortest; 
      sockFortest = new QTcpSocket( this->parent() );
      if( connectToServer() == true )
      {
         qDebug() << " YEEEE CONNECTED AGAIN finally ";
      }
  }
  if( sockFortest->state() == QTcpSocket::ConnectedState )
   {
      qDebug() << " YEEEE CONNECTED";
      sigSendData();
   }
}


void ClientForTest::connectedToTest( )
{
  QByteArray block;
  QDataStream out( &block, QIODevice::WriteOnly );

  out.setVersion( QDataStream::Qt_4_3 );

  QString stripCmd = getStoreMsgFrmCliReq(); // received info for some other function I havnt shown that func here

   out << quint16( 0 ) << stripCmd;

  out.device()->seek( 0 );

  out << quint16( block.size() - sizeof( quint16 ) );

  qDebug()<<" yeeeee connected state...";

  sockFortest->write( block );

  //reset storeLineEditMessage
  storeLineEditMsg.clear();
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged the application to see in which line exactly it crashes?

Comment: @BowDzone, yes it crashes in constructor of ClientForTest

Comment: @Bowdzone, if I take all connection defined in constructor to function executeSignals() it works fine . But now I am wondering I have addded too many delete and new calls. Is there is better way to do it?

Comment: You don't have to delete the `QTcpSocket` object every time you disconnect and create a new instance of it every time you connect. Just have one instance that you initialize for example in the constructor. But the problem seems to be your `ClientForTest` constructor. You connect signals of the `sockFortest` object, but this object hasn't been initialized. You are using an uninitialized pointer there.

Comment: @thuga, thanks , well yes i realised that and moved all connect functions to executeSignals function and now it doesnt crash.  Now my question is  in function "ConnectToserver" I am creating new instance of QTcpSocket  so technically i need to delete it in disconnectToServer() function ?

Comment: @thuga ->>>> what you mean by " You don't have to delete the QTcpSocket object every time you disconnect and create a new instance of it every time you connect. " ....  I guess I am only creating instance in connectToServer function.

Comment: Exactly. You create a new `QTcpSocket` object every time you establish a new connection. And you delete that object when you disconnect. I don't know how exactly your application works, but it seems unnecessary. You can just create the `QTcpSocket` object once in the constructor and use that instance. `QTcpSocket` a subclass of `QObject` so [as long as you set a parent to it, you won't have to worry about memory leaks](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/objecttrees.html).

Comment: Thanks  Thuga for explaining

Answer (score 2):

A few things, that could all together be responsible for your crash:

- you connect the signals inside the `ClientForTest` constructor, but the socket itself is created later. That won't work. Move the line `sockFortest = new QTcpSocket(this);` to the constructor, before connecting
- Same line, use `this` instead of `this->parent()`
- And finally: There are multiple places you create/delete the socket. Don't do it. Create the socket inside the constructor with `this` as parent, and that's it. In your `connectToServer`, establish the connection, and in `disconnectToServer`, close it using `disconnectFromHost`. Same goes for the `startClient` and `stopClient`. Create the object once and just use the connect/disconnect functions, no deleting.

If code is required, I can add some.

Since it was requested, here is some more explanation:

1. Of course you can use parent, but in your case, the `ClientForTest` is an `QObject`, too. If you set the `ClientForTest` as as parent of the socket and the widget as the parent of `ClientForTest`, they will be both cleaned up properly. If you use `this->parent()`, both will be destroyed "at the same time". However, one comes first and somtimes Qt changes the order, so your socket could be destroyed before the `ClientForTest`. The destructor of `ClientForTest` would crash. That won't happen if the socket is a child of the `ClientForTest`
2. The main difference between `close()` and `disconnectFromHost()` is that the first actually closes the OS socket, while the second does not. The problem is, after a socket was closed, you cannot use it to create a new connection. Thus, if you want to reuse the socket, use `disconnectFromHost()` otherwise `close()`

And regarding 3. and 4.:
What you are doing is creating the `ClientForTest` when the user clicks connect, and delete it as soon as he clicks disconnect. But thats no good design (IMHO). Since `tcpSockForTest` already is a member of the class, create it (via new) inside the constructor, and delete it in the destructor (optionally, because if you pass the widget as parent, Qt will delete it for you).

Comment: Thanks Mate, Quite informative. I guess the main problem was connect functions in constructor. Which I have rectify and things look better but obviously for learning purpose can You please explain                                 1) why should I use "this" instead of " this->parent()" . My main idea to use parent was to link it main widget class and when we close mainwidget it will destroy client as well.                                                                      2) disconnectToServer func-> shall I not use sockFortest->close();

Comment: 3)startClient -> i have created using new .. if I dont use new how would I create object?                                                                                                      4) StopClient -> simarily I am dleting created socket in stopClient. Do you suggest better way of doing this?  My reason for asking is to remove flaws for my code .